# How to escape a delimiter by doubling the delimiter in a regex

Tags: c#, regex

I need to split a string on a delimiter, but not where the delimiter is doubled.

For instance `"\m55.\m207|DEFAULT||DEFAULT|55||207"` once split should result in

- \m55.\m207
- DEFAULT||DEFAULT
- 55||207

I'm trying to do this with a regex. If it makes a difference, I'm using C# `System.Text.RegularExpression.Regex`.

So far I have `"[^|]\|[^|]"` but that doesn't handle where an escaped delimiter is next to the delimter. IE `|||`

I'm sure there is a solution on the net, but I've tried searching with multiple different terms and couldn't find the right combination of terms to find it.

How do I escape the delimiter by doubling it in a regex? Or if there is a simpler solution what is it?

**EDIT**

Here is a more complicated example:

Input: "\m55.\m207|DEFAULT||DEFAULT|||55||207"
Expected output:

- "\m55.\m207"
- "DEFAULT||DEFAULT||"
- "55||207"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?<=[^|](?:\|{2})+)\|(?!\|)|(?<!\|)\|(?!\|)
```

You need to use `lookarounds` to make sure split happens on only one `|`.

[See Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c%3d%5b%5e%7c%5d(%3f%3a%5c%7c%7b2%7d)%2b)%5c%7c(%3f!%5c%7c)%7c(%3f%3c!%5c%7c)%5c%7c(%3f!%5c%7c)&i=%5cm55.%5cm207%7cDEFAULT%7c%7cDEFAULT%7c55%7c%7c207%0d%0a%5cm55.%5cm207%7cDEFAULT%7c%7cDEFAULT%7c%7c%7c55%7c%7c%7c%7c207&o=m)

Comment: No it doesn't. The second match in the second example in your demo matches against all 3 ||| not just the last |.

Comment: Not quite perfect as it thinks |||| is ||| followed by a delimiter, but close enough.

Answer (score 3):

Because your demo is so simple,and you just want to split with single `|`,so I can use `\b` here

```
string txt = @"\m55.\m207|DEFAULT||DEFAULT|55||207";
string patten = @"\b\|\b";
foreach (var str in Regex.Split(txt, patten))
{
    Console.WriteLine(str);
}
```

Comment: This fails with a double followed by a delimiter.